# KIVY - Error with text input .kv

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Here is my code;

Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.factory import Factory
import sqlite3
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class LoginRoot(BoxLayout):
    username = ObjectProperty()
    password = ObjectProperty()


    def login_form(self):
        username = (self.username.text)
        password = (self.password.text)
        f = open("text/name.txt", "w")
        f.write("%s" % username)
        f.close()
        f = open("text/pass.txt", "w")
        f.write("%s" % password)
        f.close()

    def log_form(self):
        print ("Hi")

    def id_form(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        current_weather = Factory.Code()
        self.add_widget(current_weather)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db/test')
        c = conn.cursor()
        se = open("text/name.txt", "r")
        username = se.read()
        c.execute("SELECT password from userin where username = '%s'" % username)
        se.close()
        d = c.fetchone()
        f = open("yes.txt", "w")
        f.write("%s" % d)
        f.close()
        d = open("yes.txt", "r")
        d = d.read()
        ser = open("text/pass.txt", "r")
        password = ser.read()
        if d == password:
            usernow = ("%s" % username)
            print usernow



class DisocialApp(App):

    pass

class Code(BoxLayout):
idcode = ObjectProperty()

def ids_form(self):
     print (self.idcode.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DisocialApp().run()
```

Disocial.kv
    LoginRoot:

```
<LoginRoot>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    username: user_input
    password: pass_input
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: user_input
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: pass_input
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Login"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.login_form()
        Button:
            text: "Check Places"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.id_form()

<Code@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    idcode: id_input
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: id_input
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Login"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: app.root.ids_form()
```

I know get this error;

```
File "/home/seandowney/PycharmProjects/SchoolShow/disocial.kv", line 43, in <module>
     on_press: app.root.ids_form()
 AttributeError: 'LoginRoot' object has no attribute 'ids_form'
```

What I want is to enter the text from (self.idcode.text) and print it.

I have tried multiple things but to no avail and I am getting extremely confused.
I believe that
    idcode = ObjectProperty()
should behave like username and password?

Comment: your LoginRoot class has no idcode...  I think you are misunderstanding `class@parent_class` syntax for kvlang  (see http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html)

Comment: @JoranBeasley maybe I am missing something here but still it makes no sense to me?

Comment: since you removed the ids_form method from LoginRoot ... you cannot execute it in button.on_press ...

Comment: how do I know execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you define something like this in your kv file

```
<RootLogin>
     ....
<Code@BoxLayout>
     idcode = ...
```

this is roughly equivelent to

```
class RootLogin:
     ...
class Code(BoxLayout):
     idcode = ...
```

so why would you think you could do this

```
a = RootLogin()
a.idcode    #idcode is an attribute of Code ... not RootLogin
```

Im not sure what you are expecting this stuff to do so I cant help much more than that

Comment: so how do i edit on_press: root.id_form() to run the Code class?

Answer (score 1):

> idcode = ObjectProperty()

This is the only place that you set idcode for that class. The default value is None, therefore you get the given error.

You do set the idcode property of your Code class, but never access this. I'm not sure what you think should be accessing it, please elaborate on what you think should happen if it's still not clear to you what is wrong.

Comment: I think that by doing what I have done, it will follow the same principal of username and password. I thought that idcode = ObjectProperty() was just an importer.

Comment: if your class has idcode defined in its kv file then yes it imports ... but you have no widget class `Code` (which is the widget that would have this property)

Comment: @JoranBeasley so I make a new Code class? I thought I could go from the original class.

Comment: you defined a widget definition for `Code`,  which is a subclass of `BoxLayout` this is the only widget class that you defined with `idcode` ... you need to either have idcode be part of <LoginRoot> or use the <Code> class somehow to provide your idcode to the <LoginRoot> class... @ImSeanDowney what I would recommend is re-reading the documentation for kivy and start with a copy/paste of one of their existing examples ... then modify it to fit your needs ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have fixed it to work above but now with a new error. I have edited the above code if you wouldn't mind having a look for me?